# Uploadify: passing variables

Tags: php, javascript, uploadify

I'm using uploadify and I don't know how to retrieve data. In my index file I'm doing:

```
'scriptData' : {'value' : '1')
```

And then I don't know how to retrieve this value from uploadify.php. I tried `$_REQUEST['value']` and many more other options and still doesn't get it.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What does a `print_r($_POST);` yield? Can you show the full uploadify statement the scriptData line is in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you are using, but for me, I grab the data with `$_GET`.  So for your example, it would be `$value = $_GET['value']`.